# How to use JavaScript/JQuery to display summary of all HTML input values in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to display all my HTML input values on the last page of a form (before hitting the "submit" button), however, I can't get the values to print out on the page.

Here is what I've attempted so far, and when I run this, the values come up as blank on the final page. Is there perhaps a better approach than this?

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="tab">
    <label>Start Point</label>
    {{ form.start_point(placeholder="Start point..", oninput="this.className = ''", id="start_point") }}
    <label>QC</label>
    {{ form.qc(placeholder="QC...", oninput="this.className = ''", id="qc") }}
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <label>Input S3 Bucket</label>
    {{ form.input_uri(placeholder="(e.g. s3://pipeline-run/fastqs/)...", oninput="this.className = ''", id="input_uri") }}
    <label>Output S3 Bucket</label>
    {{ form.output_uri(placeholder="(e.g. s3://pipeline-run/results/)...", oninput="this.className = ''", id="output_uri") }}
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#start_point').change(function(){
        $('#start_point_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#qc').change(function(){
        $('#qc_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#input_uri').change(function(){
        $('#input_uri_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#output_uri').change(function(){
        $('#output_uri_label').text($(this).val());
    });
});

</script>
```

**UPDATE 1**:
HTML result of doing "inspect" on the area between the input labels.

```
<input id="input_uri" name="input_uri" oninput="this.className = ''" placeholder="(e.g. s3://pipeline-run/fastqs/)..." required="" type="text" value="" class=""> == $0
```

**UPDATE 2:**
my Form class where I define the user inputs

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextField, SubmitField, IntegerField, SelectField, validators
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

class InputForm(FlaskForm):

    bucket_choices = [("", "---")] + [("", bucket["Name"]) for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]]

    stack_name = StringField('STACK NAME', validators=[validators.required()])
    deploy_bucket = SelectField('PIPELINE DEPLOYMENT BUCKET', validators=[validators.required()], choices=bucket_choices)

    input_uri = StringField('INPUT BUCKET', validators=[validators.required()])
    output_uri = StringField('OUTPUT BUCKET', validators=[validators.required()])
```

**UPDATE 3:**
I have multiple inputs that have dropdown options, but when they're printed out on the final form page, each of those inputs is having the total set of selected options printed out.

How it looks:

```
Pipeline Deployment Bucket: CFNTemplateClaudia_Sandboxfastq---GRCh38-referencesGRCh38wgs---
Key Pair: CFNTemplateClaudia_Sandboxfastq---GRCh38-referencesGRCh38wgs---
Start Point: CFNTemplateClaudia_Sandboxfastq---GRCh38-referencesGRCh38wgs---
QC: CFNTemplateClaudia_Sandboxfastq---GRCh38-referencesGRCh38wgs---
```

How it **should** look:

```
Pipeline Deployment Bucket: CFNTemplate
Key Pair: Claudia_Sandbox
Start Point: fastq
QC: ---
```

Comment: are you using Angular.js or another framework? i.e. what are the curly brackets in your HTML? Possibly http://www.qcforms.com, if so you should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Including jQuery

Comment: @mb21: No, this is actually a response I got in another question as a solution to my problem. I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and the like yet.

Comment: @claudiadast Right click the area between the labels (i.e. where the `{{...}}` generates the inputs), click inspect and post that HTML.

Comment: Well, this is certainly not plain JavaScript... but @zer00ne seems to know what you're talking about though, even if nobody else does ;-)

Comment: Please EDIT your question and provide the code there (formatted).

Comment: @zer00ne: see update in question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want; if you fill the `input` areas, the `span` tag updates its content:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#my_form').change(function(){
    var str = "First name: " + $( "#name" ).val() + "<br>Last name: " + $( "#surname" ).val() +"<br>";

    $('#check_before_submit').html( str );
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form {
  margin: 20px;
}
label, input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#check_before_submit {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Form</h2>

<form id="my_form" action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="name">First name: </label><input type="text" id="name" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="Your name here...">
  <br>
  <label for="surname">Last name: </label><input type="text" id="surname" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="Your surname here...">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<span id="check_before_submit"></span>
```

JSFiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/5wn32Lzx/)

Styled layout on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/details/MqvzYj/)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. The only thing is, it's not showing the values for my inputs that have dropdown options.

Comment: Thank you! Take a look here (https://api.jquery.com/change/): there is an example with a dropdown menu; is that your case?

Comment: In my HTML, I don't have the `<select>` tags as in the example from your link. The part that specifies my inputs as dropdown comes from `SelectField` instances in my Form class (see update 2).

Comment: Are you using this one (https://maximilianpichler.github.io/material-ui-selectfield/)?

Comment: Yes it looks like that. And when I try your updated demo, it prints out all the values for my dropdown inputs for each one. (see update 3)

Comment: In your "update 2" there is python code... searching for `flask_wtf`, I understood that you are using `Flask` (https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) "a Python web development framework"... Sorry, I'm not familiar with it; maybe it's better add a flask tag in this topic, but, maybe you can also avoid it: is it necessary use it for you task?

Comment: Yes I need to use Flask unfortunately :/ But here is an update on your demo demonstrating the current issue (i.e. what happens when you have multiple inputs with dropdown options): https://jsfiddle.net/5wn32Lzx/16/

Comment: Check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/5wn32Lzx/ You need to refer to different `select` tags by using their `ID` attribute, for example, to distinguish them :)

Comment: Awesome, it works now! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Happy for you :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What about using `$.serialize()`?

This will get you all the variables with their values within a form that would be sent when that form is submitted:

```
var Str=$('form').serialize();
```

The string will be in URL-syntax (like generated by submitting a form with `method="get"`).